# where does the force direction point in pivot/see-saw system

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, torque, centripetal-force

[image]my question is *simple though I could not find any possible answer*
lets saw we have unbalanced seesaw that is having more force in the left the unbalanced system will cause **circular movenemt** of the side my question what kind of vector calculations are done to determine the **instantaneous resultant forces** that cause **the overall circular motion**

regards

Comment: Put a labelled picture **in** your post, not a link to a photo, please.  Do you know the cross product of vectors, just wondering if you do.

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Like CountTo10 says, a nice sketch of what we are looking for would help. Also, I would appreciate to see a few attempts from your side and a more specific description of which step you are stuck at - it would be nice if you could edit your question a bit to reflect that :)

Comment: Please could you explain the directions of the forces in your diagram. All of the forces are gravitational, so they act vertically downwards at all times. Some of the forces in your diagram are inclined to the vertical. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The forces on the see-saw are all acting in the same direction - vertically. As the see-saw turns these forces remain vertical. So a vector calculation is not necessary.

[image]

The centre of mass of the see-saw does not move up or down. The plank only turns about the pivot. So the forces on the plank - the weights of the riders $F1$ and $F2$ and of the plank $W$, and the normal reation $N$ from the pivot - are balanced : $F1+F2+W=N$.

The net moment of forces (torque) which tends to turn the plank is $(F2-F1)L=F3*L$. (I assume that the pivot lies at the centre of the plank, so there is no moment due to its weight $W$.) This moment is equivalent to a 'couple' - ie two equal forces $F3$ acting in opposite directions a distance $L$ apart. This 'couple' causes the see-saw to turn about the pivot.